# Split layer based on contiguous area? (PS:CS4)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs4

Is there a way to split a layer based on contiguous area?

So that, for instance, a layer with 20 'islands' of solid colour, separated by a sea of full transparency, would produce 20 new layers for each island?

Comment: Contagious? A diseased area? I think you may have used the wrong word there. And are you seeking to extract elements based on a break in a *continuous* field of color or do you just want pieces separated?

Comment: @scott - aw, whoops!  I actually wanted "contiguous" it seems but yeah, pieces seperated.  I finally found a script after searching for a while, here:  https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/split-to-layers/

Comment: Ah, just saw you found a script to do this right after posting my answer. Glad you were able to find a good solution!

Comment: You'd want to select them with maybe the lasso tool and right-click and cut as new layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this by hand, you could try the following:

1. With your island layer selected, use the magic wand tool to select one island
2. Ctrl + J (or CMD + J if you're on a Mac) to create a new layer with the selected pixels copied into it.
3. Repeat for the rest of your islands.

Comment: While a good answer, the wand tool will select an object based on its tolerance value for its pixels, the script mentioned in the above comment works exactly as expected!